# Get user ranks in multiple leaderboard

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize and I have a table in this way:

```
+--------+-------------+--------+
| userId | leaderboard | points |
+--------+-------------+--------+
|      1 | lead1       |     10 |
|      1 | lead2       |     20 |
|      1 | lead1       |      5 |
|      2 | lead2       |     10 |
|      2 | lead1       |     10 |
|      2 | lead1       |     15 |
|      3 | lead2       |     15 |
+--------+-------------+--------+
```

I have been using rank() for creating a ranking of who user has more points, or who users has more points for a given leaderboard (lead1 or lead2), but now I need to find the current rank of a user in the different leaderboards (in the example table are two but can be n), So, I need something like:

for user 1:

- user 1 - lead1 - 15 points - rank 2
- user 1 - lead2 - 20 points - rank 1

for user 2:

- user 2 - lead1 - 25 points - rank 1
- user 2 - lead2 - 10 points - rank 3

for user 3:

- user 3 - lead2 - 15 points - rank 2

I have been working with SQL for a while, but this is becoming a little complex.

Comment: take a look at [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: user 1 has two scores in lead1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/MHOC86525)**

```
WITH total_points as (
     SELECT   "userId", "leaderboard", SUM("points") as  "points"
     FROM Table1
     GROUP BY "userId", "leaderboard"
)     

SELECT "userId", "leaderboard", "points",
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "leaderboard" ORDER BY "points" DESC) as ranking
FROM total_points    
ORDER BY "userId", "leaderboard"
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Remember you have `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()`

https://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/